# Regex match for text

Tags: regex

I am tring to create a regex to match the content between numbered lists, e.g. with the following content:

1) Text for part 1
2) Text for part 2
3) Text for part 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) should work, assuming you haven't got any thing formatted like "1)" or the like inside of the sections:

```
\d+\)\s*(.*?)\s*(?=\d+\)|$)
```

Explanation:

- `\d+\)` gives a number followed by a `)`.
- `\s*` matches the preceding whitespace.
- `(.*?)` captures the contents non-greedily.
- `\s*` matches the trailing whitespace.
- `(?=\d+\)|$)` ensures that the match is followed by either the start of a new section or the end of the text.

Note, it doesn't enforce that they must be ascending or anything like that, so it'd match the following text as well:

```
4) Hello there 1) How are you? 5) Good.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the following (PCRE):

```
(?:\d+\)\s*(.*?))*$
```

- The inner part `\d+\)\s*` matches the list number and the closing brace, followed by optional white space(s).
- `(.*?)` matches the list text, but in a non-greedy manner (otherwise, it would also match the next list item).
- The enclosing `(?:  )*$` then matches the above zero or more times, until the end of the input.

Comment: In my experience, most regex engines don't allow capture groups to be recycled, sadly.

Comment: Well then use `\d+\)\s*((?:.(?!\d\)))*)` and repeat until everything matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep in mind text after number and bracket might be any text, this would find your substrings:

```
\d\).+?(?=\d\)|$)
```

EDIT:

To get rid of whitespace and return only text without a number, get group 1 from following match:

```
\d\)\w*(.+?)(?=\d\)|$)
```

To get number in group(1) and text in group(2) use this:

```
(\d)\)\w*(.+?)(?=\d\)|$)
```